# what is this usage of けど?

Tags: meaning

Very often I'll see a whole sentence said/written but then another sentence with けど at the end that is related to the previous sentence.

e.g.

> この広い中庭には、あの校舎以外にも実技訓練や試験などが行われる闘技場や、様々な儀式の行われる大聖堂などが存在している。
>
> まあ、休み時間なんかにそこらの芝生とかで休んでる学生も多いけ**れど**。

Out of the 7 definitions in [大辞林](http://www.excite.co.jp/dictionary/japanese/?search=%E3%81%91%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A9%E3%82%82&match=beginswith&itemid=DJR_keredomo_-020):

> 一  （ 接助 ）
>   活用語の終止形に接続する。
>
> 1. ある事柄に，それと逆の，または関係のうすい事柄を結びつける。 「登りは苦しい－，山頂はすばらしい」 「ちょっと淋しそうな顔だ－，美しい人だ」
> 2. 前置きを本題に結びつける。 「つまらない物です－，お受け取りください」 「勝手な言い分です－，帰らせてください」
> 3. 二つの事柄を単に結びつける。 「本が届いている－，支払いはすんだの」 「日本の象徴という－，富士山はほんとにすばらしい」
>
> 二  （ 終助 ）
>   活用語の終止形に接続する。
>
> 1. 事実とは反対の事柄を願う気持ちを表す。 「もうすこし背が高いといいのだ－」
> 2. 実現しそうにない，はかない願いを表す。 「ちょっとでも晴れてくれるとありがたい－」
> 3. 軽蔑し，軽んじる気持ちを添える。 「どうせろくなことはあるまい－」
> 4. はっきり言わず，遠回しに述べる気持ちを表す。 「そろそろお時間です－」 〔くだけた言い方では，「けれど」「けども」「けど」などの形で使われることが多い〕

Which suits the usage seen here?

Answer (score 3):

There could be a couple of different ways to explain the 「けれど」 in the context in question, but mine would be the following.

It is the case of [接続助詞]{せつぞくじょし} for the definition/usage #1 but used as a [終助詞]{しゅうじょし} as far as positioning in the sentence.

> 「ある[事柄]{ことがら}に，それと[逆]{ぎゃく}の，または[関係]{かんけい}のうすい事柄を[結]{むす}びつける。」
>
> My TL of that is: "Linking a matter to another that is contrary to or remotely related to it"

The passage provided is about the "original & official" purposes of the [中庭]{なかにわ} = "courtyard" and how it is actuallly often used on a daily basis.

Original: Use for practical training, examinations, ceremonies, etc.

Actual: Place for students to lie down during breaks.

Since there exists a wide gap between the two, 「けれど」 is used to connect them.  As you stated at the beginning, this usage of 「けど」、「けれど」, etc. is ***extremely*** common.

For comparison, it is close in nuance to the word "though" in English when it is attached to the end of a sentence in informal speech.

Answer (score 1):

Both for this case, I believe, because:

The courtyard in itself serves as the place for trainings, examinations and ceremonies, which are dedicated or meaningful activities. Then this 'けど' adds "それと逆の，または関係のうすい事柄" (opposite/less related) activities by students to take a rest or be lazy.

This is related with:

> ある事柄に，それと逆の，または関係のうすい事柄を結びつける。 「登りは苦しい－，山頂はすばらしい」 「ちょっと淋しそうな顔だ－，美しい人だ」

"まあ、… けれど。" is used to express a cynical feeling, in this case, the place does not always serve the original purpose and is used by some students to take a rest.

This is related with:

> 軽蔑し，軽んじる気持ちを添える。 「どうせろくなことはあるまい－」

Other examples of "まあ、… けれど。" I think of.

- 今年中に売上高100億を達成することになっている。まあ、絵に描いた餅だと思うけれどね
- We are supposed to achieve the total sale of 100 million yen, although I suspect it would be a pie in the sky.