# What does this けど at the end of the sentence mean?

Tags: meaning

> 「お兄ちゃん、わたし、病気のことなんとなく分かっていた。」
>   「どうせお兄ちゃんのことだから一人で悩んでいるんじゃないかと思ったけど」

I don't really see what would come after the けど in this sentence.
Can anyone help explain?

Comment: けど is commonly used as a softener at the end of a sentence. I often think of this as adding a "although....." or "but" nuance to the sentence. For example, ”。。。値段はちょっと高いと思うけど" could be translated as "Although I think the price is a little high..." Try flipping the order of the two sentence in your example passage and see if that makes more sense.

Comment: Also take a look at [this question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5010). けど/けれど/が/etc do not always strongly carry the meaning of "however", but it can be more like "..., though", "well..." or "you know..."

Comment: Chocolate, are you saying that the sentence is inversed (i.e. どうせお兄ちゃんのことだから一人で悩んでいるんじゃないかと思ったけどお兄ちゃん、わたし、病気のことなんとなく分かっていた) or are you saying that there is another unspoken part?

Comment: I don't think there's another unspoken part. In my previous (removed) comment I tried to say the けど in your example is not a 終助詞 but a 接続助詞, because you'll see it doesn't fit any of the definitions of 終助詞 in [大辞林](http://www.excite.co.jp/world/j_dictionary/ITEM-DJR_keredomo_-020/beginswith/%E3%81%91%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A9%E3%82%82/?itemid=DJR_keredomo_-020) or [デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/68969/meaning/m0u/). I think your けど is closest to the one explained in [this answer](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21249/9831).